# Augmentation in torch vision transform is not working as expected

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, torchvision

I'm developing a CNN using pytorch. my model gives good accuracy on both training and test set without augmentation but I wanted to learn augmentation so I have used torchvision transforms for the augmentation and after applying the augmentation model started doing worst and loss is not at all decreasing. so I tried to debug and observed that the augmented image looks distorted/unexpected can somebody please help me solve this.

**custom datset**

```
class traindataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self,data,train_end_idx,augmentation = None):
        '''
        data: data is a pandas dataframe generated from csv file where it has columns-> [name,labels,col 1,col2,...,col784]. shape of data->(10000, 786)
        
        '''
        self.data=data
        self.augmentation=augmentation
        self.train_end=train_end_idx
        self.target=self.data.iloc[:self.train_end,1].values
        self.image=self.data.iloc[:self.train_end,2:].values#contains full data
        
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.target);
    def __getitem__(self,idx):
        
        self.target=self.target
        self.ima=self.image[idx].reshape(1,784) #only takes the selected index
        if self.augmentation is not None:
            self.ima = self.augmentation(self.ima)
        
        return torch.tensor(self.target[idx]),self.ima
```

**Augmentation used**

```
torchvision_transform = transforms.Compose([
    np.uint8,
    transforms.ToPILImage(),
    transforms.Resize((28,28)),
    transforms.RandomRotation([45,135]),
    transforms.ToTensor()
    ])
```

**Augmented image(PFA for the picture)**

```
transformed=torchvision_transform(x)
plt.imshow(transformed.squeeze().numpy(), interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

**Normal image**

```
x=data.iloc[:1,2:].values
plt.imshow(x.reshape(28,28), interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

[image: with augmentation]

[image: without augmentation]

**The first image is with augmentation and the second image is without augmentation.
if you want you can play with the code [here](https://www.kaggle.com/ashwathshetty/test-tmnist-pytorch/notebook) without downloading anything.**

Comment: Did you make sure it was the same original image?

Comment: Yes, i have and its the same original image @Ivan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the `transforms.Resize()` function did not correctly reshape the tensor. Reshaping first seems to fix the issue and produce correct images (you did this step for the albumentations section).

```
transformed = torchvision_transform(x.reshape(28,28))
```

Comment: yes, you are right @DNy . i have corrected the code. but what i'm wondering now is, augmentation with albumentation with the same parameters gives a very good result but with torchvision transform it's performing worse. any idea why?

Comment: @AshwathShetty Are you sure they are the same? Looking quickly at your code doesn't albumentation include more augmentations such as RandomBrightnessContrast and HorizontalFlip?

Comment: the one you are seeing is not the updated code I guess(you can check now for the updated code),  even after keeping both torch vision transform and albumentation exactly the same, the torchvision transform loss is not at all decreasing, the accuracy I'm getting without augmentation is not even anywhere near to that with torchvision augmentation. with torch vision augmentation loss is not at all decreasing even after 100 epoch. i have even tried not applying any transformation except converting it to ToTensor() in torch vision transform but still not working. @DNy